# "zip file is empty" when installing RTC Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, rtc, rational-team-concert

I'm trying to install the RTC-Client-p2Repo-4.0.5.zip (290.9 MB) eclipse plugin in Eclipse Luna version 32 bit on Linux. After selection the jar file and hitting finish, I get the error at the bottom.  The jar file size is 290.9 MiB (305,030,442 bytes) and I am able to extract it.

```
An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
Error reading signed content.
zip file is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

An RTC 4.x+ is meant to be installed in an Eclipse 3.6+ (as in "[Install RTC Eclipse Client 4.0 into an existing Eclipse 3.6.2 using Installation Manager](https://jazz.net/library/article/949)")

The support for a latest [Eclipse 4.4 Luna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Name) is not guaranteed.

Comment: I just tried installing the latest RTC 5.0.1 plugin and am getting the same error.

Comment: @user994165 was it the https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/5.0.1/RTC-Eclipse-Client-Extension-repo-5.0.1.zip link (the "Client for Eclipse IDE (Extension Install)")?

Comment: I don't think that's it.  I want the Eclipse plugin: https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/5.0.1/RTC-Client-p2Repo-5.0.1.zip

Comment: @user994165 otherwise, the only instance of a similar error message was https://jazz.net/forum/questions/98841/installation-error-error-unzipping-file (simple reboot)

Comment: @user994165 Eclipse plugin should be the "Extension install"

Comment: I downloaded the Extension install, but now that zip file, but that file isn't recognized as an Eclipse plugin when I install.  I'm not sure what is the relationship between the p2 file and this extension file.

Answer (score 1):

I re-installed eclipse and that fixed the issue.  The ".eclipse" folder may need to be removed too, although I didn't see one in my Linux VM.

Answer (score 1):

***Issue Identified & Solved***
This issue arises when u try to retrieve the codBase from RTC repository to your local Workspace.
Usually u might be facing following issue :

1. Jar files in your project gets corrupted due to inevitable pushing of code in RTC repository as you would have been getting the following error where in my case Platform.jar was corrupted.

   ```
   WARNING: Failed to process JAR [jar:file:/D:/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ProjectName/WEB-INF/lib/platform.jar!/] for TLD files
   ```

Solution :

1. Try Replacing the corrupted jar files in your workspace at the respective location.
2. Try to push fresh/updated code in RTC repository,so the jar files wont get corrupted

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to go through Help-->Eclipse Marketplace, search for the plugin and install it from there.